# Combining $or and $and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

How would you do the following sql in Mongo?

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (sender='me' AND recipient='them') OR (sender='them' AND recipient='me')
```

psuedocode example of query:

```
(sender == me && recipient == them) || (sender == them && recipient <= me)
```

I am trying to get all messages which I ('me') have sent to 'them' OR the other way round (all messages which I have received from 'them').

I cannot get $or and $and to work nicely together...

I am using Mongo 3.2.8 and Mongoose (with Node.js)

Comment: try: `find({$or : [{ $and : [ {sender : "them" }, { recipient : "me" } ] }, { $and : [ {sender : "me" }, { recipient : "them" } ] }]})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried.. created a sample dataset below and looks like it works

try this

```
> db.messages.insert({"sender":"me","recipient":"them"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.messages.insert({"sender":"them","recipient":"me"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.messages.insert({"sender":"a","recipient":"b"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.messages.insert({"sender":"me","recipient":"b"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.messages.insert({"sender":"them","recipient":"b"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

check the collection

```
> db.messages.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57b78b2c8d2d515b0309868e"), "sender" : "me", "recipient" : "them" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57b78b3a8d2d515b0309868f"), "sender" : "them", "recipient" : "me" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57b78b418d2d515b03098690"), "sender" : "a", "recipient" : "b" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57b78b468d2d515b03098691"), "sender" : "me", "recipient" : "b" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57b78b4c8d2d515b03098692"), "sender" : "them", "recipient" : "b" }
```

Query

```
> db.messages.find({"$or":[{"sender":"me","recipient":"them"},{"sender":"them","recipient":"me"}]});
```

output

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57b78b2c8d2d515b0309868e"), "sender" : "me", "recipient" : "them" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57b78b3a8d2d515b0309868f"), "sender" : "them", "recipient" : "me" }
```

>

Comment: Did this help in  solving your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

`{$or: [ {sender: "me", recipient:"them"}, {sender: "them", recipient:"me"} ] }`